# build all configurations and platforms in one click

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build

Using VS.NET 2013 for C++ native project, is it possible to  build `{x86, x64} * {Release, Debug}`  in one shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is more than one click ... but there is a "batch build ..." option under the build menu. It is possible to select which configurations wanted and then click build.